# Всплывающие подсказки для пcевдоэлемендов

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3

У меня есть элемент ссылки, я ему назначаю before и after , содержащие различные картинки. Почему я использую этот метод? - он позволяет, кликая по картинкам, переходить по ссылке (для меня это важно).

А задача стоит такая, сделать всплывающие подсказки при наведении, чтобы показывалось, что  означают данные картинки (пиктограммы).
Текст ссылки может иметь разную длину, и одна (обе) картинки в зависимости от условия могут отсутствовать.
Я попробовала отразить задачку схематично:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подсказки хочется, чтобы выглядели так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто положи два спана для иконок внутрь ссылки. У них будут свободны псевдоэлементы для создания подсказок.

Comment: Сейчас попробую, но звучит обнадеживающе! Спасибо